# jQuery: exclude class on click

Tags: jquery

```
//Table select
$("#reports-table tr").click(
    function() {
        var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $('#reports-right').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id);
        $('#reports-table').width(680);
    }
);
```

I currently am using this code to add a selected class to a table row and show details of the row clicked in a right 'aside'. The problem is, I have action buttons in the row--when they are clicked, becausee they are children of the tr, this function still runs...

How can I exclude a certain class?

Comment: In the click handlers for your action buttons, you could add an `event.stopPropagation()`, so the click won't propagate to the `tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) matches a given selector and jump out, for example:

```
$("#reports-table tr").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is(".actionButtonClass")) return;
    var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $('#reports-right').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id);
    $('#reports-table').width(680);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Table select
$("#reports-table tr").click(
    function(evt) {
        if (!$(evt.target).hasClass(".yourClass")) {
          var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).addClass("selected");
          $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
          $('#reports-right').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id);
          $('#reports-table').width(680);
        }
    }
);
```